# I wanna make a counter with a number that you can also put manually

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wanna make a counter like the one every food app has.
I already had the increment and decrement function, and it works perfectly.
But I wanna make that user can also put a specific number by typing it, and increment & decrement function works on that too.

how can I do that?

here is the counter function

```
  int _counter = 0;

  _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      if (isChecked = true && _counter < (widget.productDetail['stock'])) {
        _counter++;
      }
    });
  }

  _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      if (_counter > 0) {
        _counter--;
      }
    });
  }
```

and here is the counter

```
Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            // Minus
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  _decrementCounter();
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  // padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  //     right: 10),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.remove,
                                    color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            // Qty Number
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Text(
                                '$_counter',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                            // Add
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  _incrementCounter();
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.add,
                                    color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ), // Counter
```

Comment: `what article should I read for me to understand the logic?` asking for articles here will get your question closed, SO doesn't deal with asking for resources, post the code you have and explain where you're struggling

Comment: ow, okay. thx, i'll edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take input, you need to replace `Text` with `TextFiled` and use `TextEditingController` to handle the update

The code inside state

```dart
 final TextEditingController controller =
      TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue(text: "0"));

  int _parseCounter() {
    return int.tryParse(controller.text) ?? 0;
  }

  _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      controller.text = (_parseCounter() + 1).toString();
    });
  }

  _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      if (_parseCounter() > 0) {
        controller.text = (_parseCounter() - 1).toString();
      }
    });
  }
```

And replace `Text` widget with `TextField` using controller.

```dart
   TextField(
            controller: controller,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
```

Comment: GG, friend. thx for helping me